# Add/remove recepient for sending SMS

Tags: iphone, ios6, sms

I'm creating an application that has a compose SMS feature. I do not want to use the iPhone's default `MFMessageComposeViewController`. I want to know how to add and remove recipients for SMS (create bubble and remove it) using another technique.

Comment: if you are not use default MFMessageComposeViewcontroller then where is add and remove recipient...?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to compose an SMS on iOS is to use the `MFMessageComposeViewController`. Using anything else will get your application rejected in the App store.

Comment: I want to create view that is similar to default SMS composer to add and remove recipients.